# How to make if statement keep working after clicking on a button once

Tags: javascript

I will try to explain it better. I rewrote a code, to make it better as an example. As you can see I have an app to generate a number, but to generate correct number I have to click 5-15 times on a button, due to random and if statement. I want to ask how to make a process to skip incorrect numbers and give an actual answers ( which took 5-15 clicks ) only in one click. I can give more information, if you didn't understand me. Thank you very much!

*video: https://vimeo.com/251109159

```
  function getnumber() {
  var input = document.IX.onetoThou.value;

  var firstNum = input[0];

  var ranNumb = Math.floor(Math.random()*(99-00+1)+00);
  var ans = "you are right!";

  var newNumber = firstNum + ranNumb;

  if ( newNumber % 5 == 0){
    document.getElementById("newnumber").innerHTML = newNumber+" "+ans;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the generation of your number inside a *do while* loop:

```js
function getnumber() {
  var input = document.IX.onetoThou.value;
  var firstNum = input[0];
  var ans = "you are right!";
  var newNumber;
  do {
    var ranNumb = Math.floor(Math.random()*(99-00+1)+00);
    newNumber = firstNum + ranNumb;
  } while (newNumber % 5 !== 0); 

  document.getElementById("newnumber").innerHTML = newNumber+" "+ans;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generating a random integer in [0, 100) and checking to see if it's a multiple of 5, generate a random integer in [0, 20) and multiply it by 5. That guarantees that your result will be a multiple of 5 between 0 and 100.

```
var ranNumb = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) * 5;
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for input, but I have another code, here I tried to describe it in easier way, but anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

hope this might help. You have to use `if-else` rather then `if` conditional statement

```
function getnumber() {
  var input = document.IX.onetoThou.value;

  var firstNum = input[0];

  var ranNumb = Math.floor(Math.random()*(99-00+1)+00);
  var ans = "you are right!";

  var newNumber = firstNum + ranNumb;

  if ( newNumber % 5 == 0){
    document.getElementById("newnumber").innerHTML = newNumber+" "+ans;
    }else{
document.getElementById("newnumber").innerHTML = "You are wrong";
    }

  }
```